# How can I get more info from a crash error in windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows-7, error-handling, signals, mingw

#### The problem

There seems to be a problem with my application, because it crashes unexpectedly. I'm trying to solve the problem, but I have the following problem:

On Windows 7, when the application crashes, instead of getting some useful information about the crash, the following window appears:

[image: Windows 7 error]

#### The question

Is it possible to make Windows (7) **show some actual useful information**? Like a stack trace? Memory dump? A weird error code? Anything?  I highly doubt Microsoft can help me here... in fact, `checking for a solution to the problem` never found a solution for any application, I don't know why this window even exists.

I remember that on Windows XP, there was that *Error report* window, and somewhere there was a link to another window which actually displayed some information.

#### What I tried

I tried to handle application crashes myself, using signal handling. However signal handling using MinGW seems to be pretty broken: writing to a null pointer should send a SIGSEGV signal, but the program crashed. Looking up on the internet, I found [this](http://osdir.com/ml/gnu.mingw.msys/2005-01/msg00024.html) thread which led me to believe that signal handling may be broken.

Using GDB with multiple threads is giving me a lot of trouble, since there is some time-sensitive stuff being done.

#### Other note(s)

I am working on Windows 7 (obviously), using the MinGW compiler suite, Eclipse IDE.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Visual Studio, CodeBlocks, other? IDEs allow you to run your app in debug mode, and see the line of code that fails.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. I know at what line it fails, I just can't figure out why, so an error message or something would be useful. Debugging wouldn't work because at that line, I call a winapi function, no parameters that could be wrong. The problem here is the lack of useful information given by the windows error handler.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is you are not debugging. Run or attach to engine.exe from the development environment for a debug build with symbols loaded and you should have a call stack to determine what you're doing wrong. Show the offending code, error, exception, etc here after you debug if you're still stuck.

Comment: @Tibi That narrows the problem a little bit. Can you show the line of code that fails? It seems to be a buffer overflow issue or something related to memory management. Otherwise, API calls usually return an error code, not crash.

Comment: You debug these kind of problems on Windows with a minidump.  You can create one from Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab while this dialog is displayed.

Comment: I finally managed to figure it out, apparently I forgot to put a :: before calling the winapi function, so the function (class member function) was calling itself, causing a stack overflow. But still the question remains, it would be much better if windows could give me something more useful than 'looking for a solution', this doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

when this window appears, don't click Cancel. About 1 or 2 minutes later it will become another window that allow you choose a specified compiler(on my computer it's visual studio 2010) and debug.

Comment: How can I debug using visual studio, when the project is made in Eclipse? It simply doesn't work on my computer. Is it possible to use GDB for debugging?